# What modifications can I do in my simulation so Vg must not exceed 20V?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I have implemented gate driver of Buck Converter. But when input voltage exceeds 20V then Vg also exceeds 20V wich is threshold value of transistor. What modifications should I do so that my gate voltage don't exceed 20V and circuit runs properly about 20V.[image]

Comment: R3 = 10 ohms = bad efficiency. Get a proper bootstrap driver circuit.

Comment: *Vg also exceeds 20V wich is threshold value of transistor* No it is not. The threshold voltage \$V_t\$ of for example the BSB012 is between 1.0 V and 2.2 V (datasheet, electrical chars.). The 20 V is the **maximum** that you can apply without **damaging the transistor**. Also realize that a **gate voltage** (relative to ground!!!) can be 20 V but if the **source** is at 15 V then \$V_{GS}\$ will be only 5 V and you would **not** be violating the maximum rating. I agree with Andy that this isn't a proper bootstrap gate driver circuit.

Comment: it would help you and other greatly if you relay-out your schematic so its bit more clear. I believe your worry is to ensure Vgs of M1 which is your high side mosfet is not exceeded? in your case you are driving an N channel mosfet on a high side which needs to handled differently. Is there an option M1 with a P channel mosfet? If you must use N channel mosfet on high side, then we will have to either put in a much better design to bootsrapt properly(with a lot of pain) or use an N Channel gate driver Chip to simplify the life. How do you want to go.

Comment: @NoumanQaiser I have to use N channel MOSFET on high side...Which modifications could be done in bootstrap side?

Comment: There are anumber of boot strap circuits available online that would work for very basic converters(lab projects etc). But if you are building a converter that will run for longer periods and where reliability/efficiency would matter, you must explore a N Channel gate driver IC where protections for Vgs and high speed operation is very well managed and your steady state current requirements for circuit will be low.